# How to query this case with LinQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have a table with these fields:
- Service
- Employee name
- Status
I create a filter to filter service by employee name and status:
Employee can be: All, employee A, Employee B..
Status can be: All, OK, cancel

My method is use if condition to query the result like this:

```
If(Employeename.equal("All")
{
    If(Status.equal("All")
    {
        var myResult = db.Services.ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        var myResult = db.Services.Where(s=>s.Status.equal(EmployeeName))
    }
}

...
```

Is there any way to resolve this case without use "If" and with only linQ for "All" case and case you can know the variable?
My Program Code:

```
if (agent.Equals("All"))
            {
                if (holi.Equals("All"))
                {
                    if (stype.Equals("All"))
                    {
                        var myC = db.Customers.Where(s => s.Customer_Date >= date1 && s.Customer_Date <= date2).OrderByDescending(s => s.Customer_Date).ToList();
                        var newCus = new PagedData<Customer>();
                        newCus.NumberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)myC.Count() / PageSize));
                        newCus.Data = myC.Skip(PageSize * (page - 1)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
                        newCus.CurrentPage = page;
                        return PartialView(newCus);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var myC = db.Customers.Where(s => s.Customer_Date >= date1 && s.Customer_Date <= date2 && s.Services.Where(x => x.ServiceType.ServiceTypeID.Equals(stype)).Any()).OrderByDescending(s => s.Customer_Date).ToList();
                        var newCus = new PagedData<Customer>();
                        newCus.NumberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)myC.Count() / PageSize));
                        newCus.Data = myC.Skip(PageSize * (page - 1)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
                        newCus.CurrentPage = page;
                        return PartialView(newCus);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(holi.Equals("BirthDay"))
                    {
                        if (stype.Equals("All"))
                        {
                            var myC = db.Customers.Where(s => s.Customer_Date >= date1 && s.Customer_Date <= date2 && (s.BirthDay.Value.Day.Equals(DateTime.Today.Day) && s.BirthDay.Value.Month.Equals(DateTime.Today.Month))).OrderByDescending(s => s.Customer_Date).ToList();
                            var newCus = new PagedData<Customer>();
                            newCus.NumberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)myC.Count() / PageSize));
                            newCus.Data = myC.Skip(PageSize * (page - 1)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
                            newCus.CurrentPage = page;
                            return PartialView(newCus);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var myC = db.Customers.Where(s => s.Customer_Date >= date1 && s.Customer_Date <= date2 && s.Services.Where(x => x.ServiceType.ServiceTypeID.Equals(stype)).Any() && (s.BirthDay.Value.Day.Equals(DateTime.Today.Day) && s.BirthDay.Value.Month.Equals(DateTime.Today.Month))).OrderByDescending(s => s.Customer_Date).ToList();
                            var newCus = new PagedData<Customer>();
                            newCus.NumberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)myC.Count() / PageSize));
                            newCus.Data = myC.Skip(PageSize * (page - 1)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
                            newCus.CurrentPage = page;
                            return PartialView(newCus);
                        }
                    }
                    if (holi.Equals("CompanyFounded"))
                    {
                        if (stype.Equals("All"))
                        {
                            var myC = db.Customers.Where(s => s.Customer_Date >= date1 && s.Customer_Date <= date2 && (s.Agent.Founded.Value.Day.Equals(DateTime.Today.Day) && s.Agent.Founded.Value.Month.Equals(DateTime.Today.Month))).OrderByDescending(s => s.Customer_Date).ToList();
                            var newCus = new PagedData<Customer>();
                            newCus.NumberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)myC.Count() / PageSize));
                            newCus.Data = myC.Skip(PageSize * (page - 1)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
                            newCus.CurrentPage = page;
                            return PartialView(newCus);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var myC = db.Customers.Where(s => s.Customer_Date >= date1 && s.Customer_Date <= date2 && s.Services.Where(x => x.ServiceType.ServiceTypeID.Equals(stype)).Any() && (s.BirthDay.Value.Day.Equals(DateTime.Today.Day) && s.BirthDay.Value.Month.Equals(DateTime.Today.Month))).OrderByDescending(s => s.Customer_Date).ToList();
                            var newCus = new PagedData<Customer>();
                            newCus.NumberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)myC.Count() / PageSize));
                            newCus.Data = myC.Skip(PageSize * (page - 1)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
                            newCus.CurrentPage = page;
                            return PartialView(newCus);
                        }
                    }
                    if (stype.Equals("All"))
                    {
                        var myC = db.Customers.Where(s => s.Customer_Date >= date1 && s.Customer_Date <= date2 && (s.Gender.Equals(holi) || s.Job.Equals(holi))).OrderByDescending(s => s.Customer_Date).ToList();
                        var newCus = new PagedData<Customer>();
                        newCus.NumberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)myC.Count() / PageSize));
                        newCus.Data = myC.Skip(PageSize * (page - 1)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
                        newCus.CurrentPage = page;
                        return PartialView(newCus);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var myC = db.Customers.Where(s => s.Customer_Date >= date1 && s.Customer_Date <= date2 && s.Services.Where(x => x.ServiceType.ServiceTypeID.Equals(stype)).Any() && (s.Gender.Equals(holi) || s.Job.Equals(holi))).OrderByDescending(s => s.Customer_Date).ToList();
                        var newCus = new PagedData<Customer>();
                        newCus.NumberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)myC.Count() / PageSize));
                        newCus.Data = myC.Skip(PageSize * (page - 1)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
                        newCus.CurrentPage = page;
                        return PartialView(newCus);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (holi.Equals("All"))
                {
                    if (stype.Equals("All"))
                    {
                        var myC = db.Customers.Where(s => s.Customer_Date >= date1 && s.Customer_Date <= date2 && s.Agent.AgentID.Equals(agent)).OrderByDescending(s => s.Customer_Date).ToList();
                        var newCus = new PagedData<Customer>();
                        newCus.NumberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)myC.Count() / PageSize));
                        newCus.Data = myC.Skip(PageSize * (page - 1)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
                        newCus.CurrentPage = page;
                        return PartialView(newCus);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var myC = db.Customers.Where(s => s.Customer_Date >= date1 && s.Customer_Date <= date2 && s.Agent.AgentID.Equals(agent) && s.Services.Where(x => x.ServiceType.ServiceTypeID.Equals(stype)).Any()).OrderByDescending(s => s.Customer_Date).ToList();
                        var newCus = new PagedData<Customer>();
                        newCus.NumberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)myC.Count() / PageSize));
                        newCus.Data = myC.Skip(PageSize * (page - 1)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
                        newCus.CurrentPage = page;
                        return PartialView(newCus);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (holi.Equals("BirthDay"))
                    {
                        if (stype.Equals("All"))
                        {
                            var myC = db.Customers.Where(s => s.Customer_Date >= date1 && s.Customer_Date <= date2 && (s.BirthDay.Value.Day.Equals(DateTime.Today.Day) && s.BirthDay.Value.Month.Equals(DateTime.Today.Month))).OrderByDescending(s => s.Customer_Date).ToList();
                            var newCus = new PagedData<Customer>();
                            newCus.NumberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)myC.Count() / PageSize));
                            newCus.Data = myC.Skip(PageSize * (page - 1)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
                            newCus.CurrentPage = page;
                            return PartialView(newCus);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var myC = db.Customers.Where(s => s.Customer_Date >= date1 && s.Customer_Date <= date2 && s.Services.Where(x => x.ServiceType.ServiceTypeID.Equals(stype)).Any() && (s.BirthDay.Value.Day.Equals(DateTime.Today.Day) && s.BirthDay.Value.Month.Equals(DateTime.Today.Month))).OrderByDescending(s => s.Customer_Date).ToList();
                            var newCus = new PagedData<Customer>();
                            newCus.NumberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)myC.Count() / PageSize));
                            newCus.Data = myC.Skip(PageSize * (page - 1)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
                            newCus.CurrentPage = page;
                            return PartialView(newCus);
                        }
                    }
                    if (holi.Equals("CompanyFounded"))
                    {
                        if (stype.Equals("All"))
                        {
                            var myC = db.Customers.Where(s => s.Customer_Date >= date1 && s.Customer_Date <= date2 && (s.Agent.Founded.Value.Day.Equals(DateTime.Today.Day) && s.Agent.Founded.Value.Month.Equals(DateTime.Today.Month))).OrderByDescending(s => s.Customer_Date).ToList();
                            var newCus = new PagedData<Customer>();
                            newCus.NumberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)myC.Count() / PageSize));
                            newCus.Data = myC.Skip(PageSize * (page - 1)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
                            newCus.CurrentPage = page;
                            return PartialView(newCus);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var myC = db.Customers.Where(s => s.Customer_Date >= date1 && s.Customer_Date <= date2 && s.Services.Where(x => x.ServiceType.ServiceTypeID.Equals(stype)).Any() && (s.BirthDay.Value.Day.Equals(DateTime.Today.Day) && s.BirthDay.Value.Month.Equals(DateTime.Today.Month))).OrderByDescending(s => s.Customer_Date).ToList();
                            var newCus = new PagedData<Customer>();
                            newCus.NumberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)myC.Count() / PageSize));
                            newCus.Data = myC.Skip(PageSize * (page - 1)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
                            newCus.CurrentPage = page;
                            return PartialView(newCus);
                        }
                    }
                    if (stype.Equals("All"))
                    {
                        var myC = db.Customers.Where(s => s.Customer_Date >= date1 && s.Customer_Date <= date2 && (s.Gender.Equals(holi) || s.Job.Equals(holi)) && s.Agent.AgentID.Equals(agent)).OrderByDescending(s => s.Customer_Date).ToList();
                        var newCus = new PagedData<Customer>();
                        newCus.NumberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)myC.Count() / PageSize));
                        newCus.Data = myC.Skip(PageSize * (page - 1)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
                        newCus.CurrentPage = page;
                        return PartialView(newCus);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var myC = db.Customers.Where(s => s.Customer_Date >= date1 && s.Customer_Date <= date2 && s.Services.Where(x => x.ServiceType.ServiceTypeID.Equals(stype)).Any() && (s.Gender.Equals(holi) || s.Job.Equals(holi)) && s.Agent.AgentID.Equals(agent)).OrderByDescending(s => s.Customer_Date).ToList();
                        var newCus = new PagedData<Customer>();
                        newCus.NumberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)myC.Count() / PageSize));
                        newCus.Data = myC.Skip(PageSize * (page - 1)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
                        newCus.CurrentPage = page;
                        return PartialView(newCus);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to refactor it a little bit, you can take advantage of the fact that the expression isn't evaluated until you actually enumerate it.  So you can chain clauses dynamically.  Something like this:

```
var myResult = db.Services;

if (!Employeename.Equals("All"))
    myResult = myResult.Where(s => s.EmployeeName.Equals(EmployeeName));

if (!Status.Equals("All"))
    myResult = myResult.Where(s => s.Status.Equals(Status));

return myResult;
```

Basically this would append the filters one by one as appropriate.  If no filters were applied, just the original unfiltered set is returned.  In any case, the "set" itself isn't actually evaluated until the consuming code enumerates it.  (For example, by invoking `.ToList()`, which you normally don't want to do until you have to.)

Logically this intends to produce the same result as what you have, but without all of the nested conditional blocks.  Inverting conditions to flatten the nesting is [a well known refactoring pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-nested-conditional-with-guard-clauses).

Comment: Great!!! So if i have n variable to filter i only need to filter on variable i need. My mistake that i think the linQ only like this: var myS = db.services.where(conditon) and not var myS= db.services.where(condition1).where(condition2)... Thank you again. It's make my program to be short and very simple, i dont have to use many cases.

Comment: if i dont use ToList(). The error is Error 14 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Girazo.Models.Customer>' to 'System.Data.Linq.Table<Girazo.Models.Customer>' E:\Word\Taa\HoangHD\Hanoi Sky\Girazo\Controllers\CustomerCareController.cs 673 23 Girazo

Comment: @HoàngĐỗHuy: You can use `.ToList()` after all of the `.Where()` clauses have been applied, then.  It's not entirely clear from the code snippet posted in the question where you *should* use `.ToList()`.  But you *definitely* want to use it as late in the querying as possible so that the entire expression tree is sent to the data source rather than bringing the whole data source into memory and filtering there.

Comment: Thank you again!! so if i use .ToList() it's will be slower and not peromance as i dont use right?

Comment: @HoàngĐỗHuy: It depends on other factors of the logic.  As always, performance should be measured and not assumed.  When you call `.ToList()` what that does is evaluate the entire expression against the underlying data source.  If the underlying data source is already in-memory, this may have little impact.  If the underlying data source is a database, then it's usually better to build the expression first before evaluating it because databases are particularly good at querying data.  So it's preferable to offload the querying to the data source rather than bring the entire set into memory.

Comment: Thank you very much @David! Luck today with me!

Comment: Help me again! my trouble is my query through 3 related table, if i use tolist(). I will receive only null or empty cause i receive only 1 Entity when use tolist(). So maybe i must got 3 Entity then use where to filter. But if i dont use Tolist(). the error above appear. How should i do?

Comment: @HoàngĐỗHuy: I'm afraid I have *no idea* what you're describing.  But it sounds like it's enough to merit an entirely separate Stack Overflow question where you can more effectively demonstrate and describe the problem.

Comment: I just add my real code to the question. Could you please have a look?

Comment: @HoàngĐỗHuy: That code is difficult to follow, hasn't been corrected for this answer, and doesn't really describe or demonstrate the entirely separate problem you're attempting to describe now.